# How to use columns from the left table in where clause in the right select statement in SQL Server join statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I want to join a table with the output of select statement where I need to use a column `last_order_date` from Table1 in the `WHERE` clause in the select statement.

For example, see this screenshot:

[image]

I tried the following code:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM
    Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT prod_id, SUM(sales) sales_sum
     FROM Table2
     WHERE transaction_date BETWEEN t1.last_order_date AND CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
     GROUP BY prod_id) t2 
ON t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id
```

Apparently, the problem is that I can't use `t1.last_order_date`  in the WHERE CLAUSE in the right part of the join statement. Anyone can help?

Comment: Don't [delete and repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71749144/cant-use-column-from-a-table-in-where-clause-of-the-other-query-in-join-stateme) questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    Table1 t1
OUTER APPLY 
(
     SELECT t2.prod_id, SUM(t2.sales) sales_sum
     FROM Table2 t2
     WHERE t2.transaction_date BETWEEN t1.last_order_date AND CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
     AND  t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id
     GROUP BY t2.prod_id
) t2
```

From your expect result I think you can use `LEFT JOIN` like this.

```
SELECT t1.prod_id,
       MIN(t1.last_order_date) last_order_date,
       SUM(ISNULL(t2.sales,0)) sales
FROM
    Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t2.transaction_date BETWEEN t1.last_order_date 
     AND CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)
     AND  t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id
GROUP BY t1.prod_id
```

Comment: The outer apply approach didn't actually work, however, the left join approach solved the problem. Thanks a lot.